# Regular expression for Visual Studio Power Tools custom tab color to match on tabs that start with I (for Interface)

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

I'd like to colour code my tabs according to file types.

I'd like Interface files to be white.

My naming convention for interfaces is the usual

IFoo.cs
IIgloo.cs

etc

To try and colour code these I'm using this regex

```
^I([A-Z][a-z0-9]*){1}\.cs$
```

However that is colour coding

Invoice.cs
and 
IInvoice.cs

Where I would like it to only catch IInvoice.cs

Where have I gone wrong with my regex?

I thought this regex would match:

`^I` - Starts with I

`([A-Z][a-z0-9]*)` - Then has an upper case character followed by lowercase characters or numbers

`{1}\.cs$` - Ends with .cs

Other regex I've tried:

`I[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]+\.cs` - Matches both Invoice.cs and IInvoice.cs
`(?:I[A-Z]+[a-z0-9]+\.cs)` - Matches both Invoice.cs and IInvoice.cs

Comment: Did you check the case sensitivity setting? `[A-Z]` will match `a` and `z` if this setting is set as case insensitive. There is nothing else that can explain this behavior. BTW, your pattern can be written as `^I[A-Z][a-z0-9]*\.cs$` - or if you need the capturing group - `^I([A-Z][a-z0-9]*)\.cs$`

Comment: What is the regex flavor in PPT? The deleted answer suggested a valid .NET regex that would override the general case sensitivity setting: [`(?-i)^I[A-Z][a-z0-9]*\.cs$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f-i%29%5eI%5bA-Z%5d%5ba-z0-9%5d*%5c.cs%5cr%3f%24&i=Invoice.cs%0d%0aIInvoice.cs%0d%0aInvoice.cs&o=im)

Comment: I don't know what regex it uses. Other regexes I use it with (which work are) `.*\.xaml[ ]*(\[read only\])?$` for matching .xaml files. `.+ViewModel.+` for finding files that have `ViewModel` in the names. Does this help with identifying regex type?

Comment: Theres no option in PPT for setting case sensitity, so I'm thinking I just can't do what I'm trying to do :(

Comment: Those other regex are basic regexps that would work in all but POSIX BRE, thus, no. No idea how to help you if  a modifier group is not parsed correctly.